# Used normal text in combination with normal text in plot

Tags: r, expression

UPDATE: I actually found the solution myself, see below.

In R I want to add a label to a plot containing both subscript and normal text. To be more precise, I would like to use mtext() (or any other method that does the trick) to add a text below a plot. The text should look like this:

[image: The label] 

This can easily done in latex with `$B\pm t_{a/2}SE(B)$`

In R I come as far as `mtext(expression(B%+-%t[a/2]))`, which does print

[image: r so far]

But the difficulty is in geting the SE(B) part after it, because of expression treating SE(B) as a function. I've tried several combinations with paste, but to no avail. I'm sure there must be a simple solution to this, but I wasn't able to find one after quite a long search.

---

UPDATE:

Wow, found the solution myself. As I said I have tried combinations of expression and paste and was sure I tried this before, but apparently, I did not. The solution is this:

```
mtext(expression(paste(B%+-%t[a/2],"SE(B)")))
```

Comment: "(SOLVED)" in your title is unnecessary.  You can post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see you have solved this, but your final solution is much more nicely and succinctly handled by dropping the use of `paste()` and using the `~` operator to add spacing:

```
expression(B %+-% t[a/2] ~ SE(B))
```

e.g.:

```
plot(1:10, xlab = expression(B %+-% t[a/2] ~ SE(B)))
```

which gives

[image]

You can add extra spacing by using multiple `~`: `~~~` for example. If you just want to juxtapose two parts of an equation, using the `*` operator, as in:

```
plot(1:10, xlab = expression(B %+-% t[a/2] * SE(B)))
```

which gives:

[image]

It isn't immediately clear from your Q which one is preferable.

Comment: +1 for illustrating proper use of `*` in plotmath expressions. So many people use `paste` when `*` is the more compact and "express"-ive choice.